# Why did the British control Hong Kong over 99 years?

Tags: british-empire, china, united-kingdom, britain

There is different version why British Empire took control over Hong Kong.

- **Britain** helped **China** to eliminate pirates in *South China Sea*. As a sign of appreciation *China* give control of **Hong Kong** to Britain.
- **China** was weak. *Britain*, *Germany*, *Russia*, *France* and *Japan* were willing to partition *China*. In order to avoid that *China* gave *Hong Kong* to **Britain** and *Britain* sponsored **China**.

Maybe there are more variants, I do not know.

Comment: Can you provide sources for these theories?

Comment: No @DarekWędrychowski I lost it. I just remember it.

Comment: ha! "as a sign of appreciation". You might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unequal_treaty

Comment: Yes I know it should strange. No one government will give a territory as a sign of appreciation.

Comment: They forced to do because USSR gave them territory belong to Germany.

Comment: Please notify your source or your simply just imagined these 2 points by yourself ?

Comment: Of course this is not my imagination but I do not remember certain source.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Hong Kong became British colony as a result of [First Opium War](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Opium_War), which was lost by [Qing Dynasty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qing_Dynasty) of China to [United Kingdom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_of_Great_Britain_and_Ireland). It was part of agreements of [Treaty of Nanking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Nanking#Cession_of_Hong_Kong) that was signed in 1842, as well as huge war reparations.

What's important, original agreement established that Hong Kong becomes British for eternity, not for the exact amount of years. The 99 years period applied to New Territories by which the area of colony was extended in 1898 during [Second Convention of Peking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_for_the_Extension_of_Hong_Kong_Territory).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, he tried to ask why it was reduced to "only 99 years", instead of being "in perpetuity" like it was.